# JUnit suite runner to execute one method

Tags: java, junit

I have a test suite that runs all test classes

```
    @RunWith(Suite.class)
    @Suite.SuiteClasses({TestClass1.class, TestClass1.class})
    }

    public class AllTests extends TestCase {

      public AllTests(String name) {
        super(name);
      }

      public static TestSuite suite() {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite("com.myapp.test.AllTests"); 
        return suite;
      }
}
```

is it possible to implement a custom runner that will run only one method, say "onlyMethodToRun", from every class in the suite?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [`Suite.java`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/42e4651517abf251c0b455726d4c8da04f1182bf/src/main/java/org/junit/runners/Suite.java) implements a test runner that examines the classes listed in `@Suite.SuiteClasses` and uses `RunnerBuilder`s to find every test method. You should be able to reuse a lot of JUnit's code to implement a `Runner` that instead only checks for a single method on every class and perhaps uses a subclass of `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner` that overrides [`computeTestMethods`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/42e4651517abf251c0b455726d4c8da04f1182bf/src/main/java/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java#L107) to only attempt a single method.

Comment: is there any examples? cause i couldn't find anything

Comment: Start with `Suite`. Otherwise, searching the web for 'junit custom test runner' will return plenty of examples. [Conditionally ignoring JUnit tests](http://blog.xebia.com/2012/10/02/conditionally-ignoring-junit-tests/) seems related to what you're describing.